# Why getting error AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'executes_script'

Tags: python, selenium

Getting error for line self.driver.executes_script
**self.driver.executes_script("arguments[0].click();", new_notification)
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'executes_script'
None**
but their is a class name with it

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import HtmlTestRunner
import time


class Environment(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="F:\\automation\\chromedriver.exe")

    # login test case
    def test_first_page_login(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.get("http://localhost/dashboard/user/login")
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('uemail').send_keys('xyz@abc.com')
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('upwd').send_keys('1234567890')
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('upwd').send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    # login page going

    def test_going_notification_page(self):
        self.test_first_page_login()
        time.sleep(5)
        going_noti_page = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('caret')
        print(self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", going_noti_page))
        new_notification = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('fa-paper-plane')
        self.driver.executes_script("arguments[0].click();", new_notification)
        time.sleep(5)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
        unittest.main(testRunner=HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(output='F:\\automation\\reports'))
```

Comment: I suggest visiting [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a better insight on how to ask a solid question. Additionally, some code, errors, and a slightly better explanation is necessary for others to offer you help (they 1st need to understand what the actual issue is). **Please edit your post accordingly**

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/automation/environment.py", line 31, in test_going_notification_page   i am getting this error
    self.driver.executes_script("arguments[0].click();", new_notification)
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'executes_script'
None

Comment: shouldn't it be `execute_script` not `executes_script` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just have a typo:

```
self.driver.executes_script("arguments[0].click();", new_notification)
```

`executes_script` doesn't exist, but based on the api-doc you probably mean: `execute_script`

[DOC: WebDriver.execute_script](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script)